# Teradata SQL - Conditions depending on conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, teradata, where-clause, case-when

This question is a variation on an older post 
[image]

**The conditions**

If Customer_country = ‘A’

1. then Ship_country must = ‘A’
2. and Customer_number <> ‘A2’ (i.e. exclude A2)
3. and date is between x and y. (same for all Customer country)

The same logic goes for all Customer_country, where respective B2, C2, D2 Customer_numbers are excluded.

[image]

I am confused with using CASE…WHEN because it is expected to return a value.
But I am not returning any value. Please help with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `where` clause instead of `case when`

Using `||` method to combine char like `A2` or `B2` ... ,then you can exclude that.

```
SELECT *
FROM master as t1 
WHERE 
    t1.Customer_number <> t1.Customer_Country || '2'
AND 
    t1.Ship_Country = t1.Customer_Country
```

[teradata ||](https://forgetcode.com/Teradata/1292-Concatenation-Operator)

**EDIT**

if the customer_number is like '981432776',you can use `NOT IN` to exclude that.

```
SELECT *
FROM master as t1 
WHERE 
    t1.Customer_number NOT IN ('A2','B2','C2','D2')
AND 
    t1.Ship_Country = t1.Customer_Country
```

Comment: A, B, C,D , A1, A2...etc are stand-in letters for acutal country and customer numbers. 'A2' could be a customer_number like '981432776'. And I presume the conditions follow a WHERE clause.